# Rendering a Template with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, rendering

These day's I'm working into a New's Website ,and the back-end I'm writing from scratch without using any PHP Framework's.

My concern is unreasonable periodic query's against **MySQL**("What does it mean !:)")

On the first Page user would see only updated Posts ,so i thought when Page Administrator insert's a Post i will Render a **.html** File with updated newest Post's and User's will get redirected there where all Posts are there and everything is fine(no php execution no MySQL Query's against a large Database).
So far Index.php was Executed ,did a Select at MySQL and present the data ,now i want to Execute Index.php get it's content and save it as Index.html

So is there a way to call a .PHP file ,Execute it Localy and save the Output into an HTML File ,just like User's will Execute.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you need to know how to cache a script's output?

Comment: You should take a good long read about PHP and caching.

Comment: Yes it is somehow a Manual Cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. What you can do is by using Curl library, call your index.php with full url. (eg. http://127.0.0.1/index.php). So, you take output of executed index.php instead of its code. Then, by using file_put_contents function, you can save output to an index.html file.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it would be to use PHP's output buffering and store the output buffer in a file.

```
ob_start();
// process page here
$buffer = ob_get_flush(); // this will display the contents of the output buffer and return the contents into $buffer
file_put_contents('index.html', $buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a short hint:

Your php file gets data from a database and save the output of it via the output buffer and safe everything to a html file. You script just have to check whether the .html file exists or not. If not > create it; else > include it / print the content.

Rally simple and you don't have to query the db all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into something like [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) which sits in front of your web application and provides a caching layer.

Because it sits between the user and your application, it is language / framework agnostic, thus integration effort tends to be lower.

(I realise this doesn't answer your question exactly in terms of implementation detail, but I want to point out that caching internal to your application isn't the only option for reducing database load)

Answer (score 0):

Some statements to think of:

1. Databases intended to be queried. Nothing essentially wrong with "periodic query's against MySQL".
2. On the *real-world* website there will be not only **one** dynamical part: there will be things like banners, number of comments, fresh blog posts and such.
3. Stackoverflow is using such way of caching. It turns out to be **expremely annoying** when you are trying to refresh the page to get new data and it returns nothing.
4. Premature optimization is a root of all evil.